# Saving CFPropertyLists To Users Folder

Tags: cocoa, macos, unix

I'm trying to save a CFPropertyList to a location in the user's home folder.  Using the code below I'm getting errorCode = -10 (unknown error).

```
CFURLRef fileURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("~/testfile.txt"),  kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false );  

SInt32 errorCode;
Boolean status = CFURLWriteDataAndPropertiesToResource(fileURL, xmlData, NULL, &errorCode);
```

If I change the path to something like "/testfile.txt" without the '~' then everything works.  How can one save a property list to the current user's home folder?  Must one obtain the user's name first and include it in the path such as /users/toffler/testfile.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic ~ expansion is a feature of the shell.

If you are using Cocoa/Foundation, you can use the NSString methods

```
- (NSString *)stringByAbbreviatingWithTildeInPath;
- (NSString *)stringByExpandingTildeInPath;
```

otherwise, you'll have to write some code yourself to do this. Getting the user's login name and constructing the path /Users/login-name/ is **not** the correct way to do this. (While most users will have their home directory here, some will not.)

Comment: Thanks Jim.  After reading your answer I found the CoreFoundation version that I also need here.  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1549.html

Answer (score 3):

With Foundation, you can call [the `NSHomeDirectory` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory) to get the absolute path to the user's home directory. You can then use [the path-manipulation methods of NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathComponent:) or [of NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByAppendingPathComponent:), or [the equivalent function for CFURL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent), to tack a sub-path onto that.

However, please don't put files into the top level of my Home folder unless I, as the user, tell you to.

- If you want to save a file at the user's request, run a [save panel](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/), and then save it where the user told you to.
- If you want to save a preferences file, you probably should be using [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) or [CFPreferences](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/), instead of handling plists yourself.
- If you have some other reason to save a user-specific file, it should generally go into either [the chewable items folder](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSTemporaryDirectory), [the Caches folder](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains), or the Preferences folder. The two functions that I linked to are the easiest ways to access those two of those three folders; the harder way, and the only one that works on all three, is [the `FSFindFolder` function](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Folder_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSFindFolder). Unlike most of the Folder Manager, `FSFindFolder` is not deprecated and is available in 64-bit.

---

#### Updates from the year 2012

- Nowadays, you should use URLs, not paths. [NSFileManager has a method for getting a URL to a desired directory.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:)
- Stapling paths (or file URLs) together does not work in a sandboxed application, because you don't have authorization to access the path you just made up. You need to get the path (or URL) from a system API, whether it's NSFileManager, NSSavePanel, or something else.
- For saving and restoring file references, use NSURL's security-scoped bookmarks feature.
- NSUserDefaults and CFPreferences work as expected in a sandbox.
- The Folder Manager is now fully deprecated as of 10.8.
- Polluting the user's Home folder is still bad manners.

Comment: NSHomeDirectory works really well with NSString's stringByAppendingPathComponent.

Comment: Stephen Blinkhorn: Yeah, but see the rest of my answer. You really shouldn't be putting files in the top level of the Home folder unless I (the user) tell you to in a Save panel, in which case you already have the complete path and don't need to assemble it.